# Microservice database architecture for Ecommerce web app

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

I am trying to create a ecommerce project just for sake of learning spring boot, and hibernate
and I am thinking of a microservice pattern with six major services : 1.customer 2. Order 3.Product 
4.Vendor 5. Payment 6.UI Service
I am facing problem in deciding whether to put all tables in one database shared by all microservices which obviously makes the Db prone to inconsistency,or to go the standard way of creating separate DB's for all microservices.

I am not able to figure out that if I go with the second choice of separate db of a microservice then how the Entries will be updated in Orders table and Customers table. On further findings I found **Saga Pattern**.

Please provide some suggestions or any links to websites or material through which I can address the issue in an efficient way.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using micro service architecture it's better to use database per service approach.  Then you have to use SAGA pattern to handle distributed transactions. Probably you have to use RabbitMq or Kafka as a message broker to communicate with each micro service. This will give you better idea on Saga pattern [link](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html)

Since you are using multiple databases, it is no longer straightforward to implement queries that join data from multiple services. To cater that there is pattern called Command Query Responsibility Segregation (CQRS).
Read this link to get an idea [link](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/cqrs.html)